# Django Rest-Auth giving 403 when doing a GET /user/

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, get

I am trying to test some Angular 2 app code that calls the rest-auth package on my local Django server.

Using Chrome to see the header information I see the following when the GET is issued:

```
OPTIONS /rest-auth/user/ HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-csrftoken
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Referer: http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, content-type, accept, origin, authorization, x-csrftoken
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, UPDATE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 17:31:43 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

And here is what the 403 result looks like:

```
GET /rest-auth/user/ HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Referer: http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
X-CSRFToken: 

HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 17:31:43 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Do I need to do something special to get rid of the 403 error?